# Java: Aggregating multiple Stack Traces into a tree

Tags: java, arrays, tree

I would like to convert a bunch of Stacktraces (StackTraceElement[]) into a tree-like structure.
I.E. I have 3 Stack traces (simplified as Strings here) like

> StackTraceElement[] one = ["first.package.class.method()", "first.package.class.otherMethod()", "second.package.class.method()"];

> StackTraceElement[] two = ["first.package.class.method()", "first.package.class.otherMethod()", "third.package.class.method()"];

> StackTraceElement[] three = ["first.package.class.method()", "first.package.class.otherMethod()", "fourth.package.class.method()"];

The result should span those arrays into a non-duplicate tree and look somewhat like this:

- first.package.class.method()
- - first.package.class.otherMethod()
- - - second.package.class.method()
- - - third.package.class.method()
- - - fourth.package.class.method()

What would be the most efficient way to do so? Are there libraries that can already do this?

Thanks in advance!